# How can I delete a group from LDAP using java?

Tags: java, ldap

someone knows how can I delete a group from LDAP using java? and how is the best way to verify is this group is empty?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LDAP operations maps to JNDI api. According to the specification available here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ldap/operations.html, you can use following method:

**void destroySubcontext(String name) throws NamingException**

Which should destroy the named context and remove it from the namespace.

Quote from the documentation below:

"This method is idempotent. It succeeds even if the terminal atomic name is not bound in the target context, but throws NameNotFoundException if any of the intermediate contexts do not exist.

In a federated naming system, a context from one naming system may be bound to a name in another. One can subsequently look up and perform operations on the foreign context using a composite name. However, an attempt destroy the context using this composite name will fail with NotContextException, because the foreign context is not a "subcontext" of the context in which it is bound. Instead, use unbind() to remove the binding of the foreign context. Destroying the foreign context requires that the destroySubcontext() be performed on a context from the foreign context's "native" naming system.

Parameters:
    name - the name of the context to be destroyed; may not be empty"

Answer (score 1):

Use the UnboundID LDAP SDK to establish a connection to the server, then create a delete request specifying the DN of the group to delete. Transmit the delete request to the server and interpret the response.

```
DeleteRequest deleteRequest =
    new DeleteRequest("cn=entry to delete,dc=example,dc=com");

try
{
  LDAPResult deleteResult = connection.delete(deleteRequest);

  System.out.println("The entry was successfully deleted.");
}
catch (LDAPException le)
{
  System.err.println("The delete operation failed.");
}
```

If the LDAP client wishes to "empty" the group, which I take to mean "delete all attributes in the entry, LDIF can be  constructed to remove all values of an attribute:

```
##
## assume 'member' is the attribute that whose values are members:
##
dn: cn=group1,ou=group,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: member
```

'Replace' with no value deletes all values of the member attribute whether any values exist or not. 'Delete' with no value deletes all values, but there must be at least one to delete.

Generally speaking, if there is choice, the UnboundID LDAP SDK should used instead of JNDI.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)